# Как лучше переводить данные через страницу

Tags: php, html

Как лучше переводить данные через страницу?

1)Через сесии и скрытые поля

```
 session_start();
  $_SESSION['name_teacher'] = $_POST['name_teacher'];
   <input type="hidden" name="$id_school" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name_teacher'] ; ?>" />
```

2) Через скрытые поля и РОST запросы

```
    $name_teacher = $_POST['name_teacher'];
     <input type="hidden" name="$id_school" value="<?php echo $id_school; ?>" />
```

3) Или просто через сессии и без скрытых полей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты уж реши, через что, у тебя и там и там через скрытые поля все передается.
либо так

```
$_SESSION['name_teacher'] = $_POST['name_teacher'];
```

либо так

```
<input type="hidden" name="$id_school" value="<?=$_POST['id_school'];?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Через сесии и скрытые поля

Зачем лишние телодвижения? SESSION = POST, input hidden value = SESSION?

Проще input hidden value = POST